# How many LayoutInflater are instantiated in an application?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am using the Factory interface on LayoutInflater to be able to set a custom typeface on all my TextView in my application. Unfortunately there are places in my application where it doesn't work. After investigation, it seems that in the adapter of my ListView for example, the LayoutInflater used to inflate the cells is different from the one that has been used fo the rest of the application (my activity has a complex structure with Fragments).

Is this behaviour normal ? How can I make sure that the same LayoutInflater is always used, whatever the way I retrieve it ?

Thanks

Comment: **Unfortunately there are places in my application where it doesn't work.** What do mean by "it doesn't work"? As AedonEtLIRA says in their answer, post the code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

as You get reference to `LayoutInflater` from `Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` (`ViewGroup.inflate` and `Activity.getLayoutInflater` are just convenient wrappers) i presume it always returns reference to the same inflater service, until it is destroyed and recreated, and then this newly created is returned, and so on... I presume that manager object aquired from getSystemService method are sth like "normal" service's binder objects.

EDIT:
And saying above i was wrong ;)

i checked out the source code and in android.view.ContextThemeWrapper (which is activitie's super class):

```
 @Override public Object  getSystemService(String name) {
     if (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
         if (mInflater == null) {
             mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mBase).cloneInContext(this);
         }
         return mInflater;
     }
     return mBase.getSystemService(name);
 }
```

and in android.app.ContextImpl which is probably mBase Context implementation:

```
public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    ServiceFetcher fetcher = SYSTEM_SERVICE_MAP.get(name);
    return fetcher == null ? null : fetcher.getService(this);
}
```

where :
    private static final HashMap SYSTEM_SERVICE_MAP =
             new HashMap();

and ServiceFetcher is an inner class for caching and retrieving "system service instances".

What is sure there is one LayoutInflater per activity/ContextWrapper. For more observations study sources, please ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the quantity of LayoutInflaters really matters (unless you are literally thousands). But, yes, using multiple Inflaters is indeed normal. I use quite a few when working with my adapter views (as in I don't use one static one. Each adapter still only uses one).

If there are places in your code that the adapter doesn't work, you are probably missing something. I would post the code where the Inflater doesn't work.